# How to use functions like lit,lower,trim in pyspark 2.3.2

Tags: python, pyspark

How to use below functions in pyspark older versions like 2.3.2 as the same can be imported in 3.X but they are missing in older version.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, lower, upper, trim
```

This gives me error

Thanks!

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: these functions are not available in 2.3.2 hence cant import.

Comment: something is wrong with your installation, these functions `lit, lower, upper` are available since 1.3 and `trim` since 1.5

Comment: @Amit what is the PYTHONPATH? Do you have `scripts` in your path? How are you running the script, IDE, Command prompt?

Comment: Thank you for comments, it is highlighting as an import error but still works when executed!